# Compare WebElement with Timedelta

Tags: python, selenium, compare, timedelta

i have a HTML Table with 5 columns. In the third column are links and in the fifth column is a Date.

Now i want to write a code which check if the date is within the next 4 weeks and if yes, then click on the link

This is what i have so far:

```
# Set the Date
start = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d-%m-%Y')
date_in_four_weeks = now + datetime.timedelta(days=28)
project_time = date_in_four_weeks - now

# Check the date and click on link
for i in range(project_time.days + 1):
    print(now + timedelta(days=i))
    time = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css_selector')
    if time <= project_time:
        linkList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("css_selector")
        for i in range(0,len(linkList)):
            links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('SOLI')
            links[i].click()
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("test.png")
    else:
        print "No Project found"
```

If i run the code i get the error:

> TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to WebElement

Now i want to ask if there is any way how i can fix my problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: You have to convert the `time` to datetime object before comparing.

Comment: Thanks for the Information, but i´m new to python, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues you have to address.

Firstly, you're comparing to a WebElement object, as the error helpfully points out. This includes the tags and such of the HTML element you're referencing. You first want to extract the text.

Then, you need to parse this text to convert it into a Python `datetime` or `date` object. A `time` object won't do because it only stores time, and not date. Since I don't know what format your HTML date is in, I'll just point you to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) so you can see how the types work and have some idea of how to parse your data.

Finally, you'd still get an error because of trying to compare a `timedelta` object to a `date` or `datetime` object. A `timedelta` is a period of time, it doesn't relate to a specific date.

You could fix this by replacing

`if time <= project_time:`

With the same as from your print function:

`if time <= now + timedelta(days=i)`